# Same char in one string

Tags: java, string, types, char

I need to know how many chars of the same type are in one string.

I have tried this

```
String x ="(3+3)*(4-2)";
int a = x.indexOf( "(" );
```

But that only give me the first index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it would be better to put it in a separate function:

```
// accepts a string and a char to find the number of occurrences of
public static int get_count(String s, char c) {    

    int count = 0;                        // count initially 0

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)  // loop through the whole string
        if (s.charAt(i) == c)
            count ++;                     // increment every time an occurrence happens

    return count;                         // return the count in the end

}
```

You can call it like this:

```
System.out.println(get_count("(3+3)*(4-2)", '('));

// Output: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop and use the other method `indexOf(int, int)`:

```
String x ="(3+3)*(4-2)";
int a = x.indexOf( "(" );

while (a >= 0) {
    System.out.println("Char '(' found at: "+a);
    a = x.indexOf('(', a+1);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that answer between all others. It’s good to see that there are others knowing that there is that method and provide an answer without overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringUtils.countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
StringUtils.countMatches(value,"(");
```

or

```
public static int countMatches(String value, String valueToCount) {
          if (value.isEmpty() || valueToCount.isEmpty()) {
                return 0;
            }
            int count = 0;
            int index = 0;
            while ((index = value.indexOf(valueToCount, index)) !=  -1) {
                count++;
                index += valueToCount.length();
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: I don’t think that it is a good advice to add a third party library just for such a trivial task. But when copying the method’s code you should not rename the second parameter to “regex” as it doesn’t treat it like a regular expression. It’s calling `String.indexOf` which does exact matching only.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways I could think of doing this, but one of the simplest would be to simply loop the through characters in the `String`....

```
String x ="(3+3)*(4-2)";
int count = 0;
for (char c : x.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '(') {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

And just because it can be done...you could use a little regexp...(I know, overkill)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(x);
while (matcher.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what you want. If performance is critical you can make optimization with this. If you want more elegant solutions you may take a look at regex library of java.

```
int occurences = 0;
String x ="(3+3)*(4-2)";
char tolookfor = '(';
for(int i = 0; i < x.length() ; i++)
{
    if(x.charAt(i) == tolookfor)
        occurences++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    String x ="(3+3)*(4-2)";
    char[] arr=x.toCharArray();
    Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
          Integer upTo=map.get(String.valueOf(arr[i]));
           if (upTo==null) {
               upTo=0;
           }
          map.put(String.valueOf(arr[i]),upTo+1) ;
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry:map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Number of "+entry.getKey()+" in this string is: "+entry.getValue());
    }
```

out put

```
Number of 3 in this string is: 2
Number of 2 in this string is: 1
Number of 4 in this string is: 1
Number of * in this string is: 1
Number of + in this string is: 1
Number of ( in this string is: 2
Number of ) in this string is: 2
Number of - in this string is: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s unbelievable how complicated the answers to such a simple question can be.

> `x.indexOf( "(" );`
>   But that only give me the first index

Use `x.indexOf( "(", fromIndex );` to find more occurrences. Point.

By the way, if you are looking for a single char you can use `x.indexOf( '(');` and `x.indexOf( '(', fromIndex );` to be more efficient.

So the most efficient way without reinventing the wheel would be:

```
int count=0;
for(int pos=s.indexOf('('); pos!=-1; pos=s.indexOf('(', pos+1)) count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you!

```
public static int counter(String x, char y) {

    char[] array=x.toCharArray();

    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
    {
        if(y==array[i]) count++;

    }

    return (count>0)? count:0;  
}
```